# How to add an additional condition with SQL Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, inner-join, where-clause

I have tables `ROOT`, `META` & `EMETA` which contains column `REV` which will be a number. Now only `ROOT` will contain `REV` with a value 0. Other than `REV`, these tables have other columns.

I'm using a join to fetch rows with matching `REV`s from all three tables like

```
SELECT 
    R.REV, R.D1, R.D2.. 
FROM 
    ROOT R 
JOIN
    META M ON R.REV = M.REV 
JOIN
    EMETA E ON R.REV = E.REV
```

Now I want to fetch rows with 0 also from ROOT table in same query. How that is possible?

Comment: oracle or postgresql?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want two `left` joins:

```
SELECT R.REV, R.D1, R.D2, ... 
FROM ROOT R 
LEFT JOIN META  M ON R.REV = M.REV
LEFT JOIN EMETA E ON R.REV = E.REV
```

If you want to allow "missing" rows only when `ROOT(REV)` is `0`, then add a `WHERE` clause to the query:

```
WHERE (M.REV IS NOT NULL AND E.REV IS NOT NULL) OR (R.REV = 0)
```